# how to get the list same as original list in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

input list is lst format, example SI.lst
the inpit display will be like example below:

[image]

After the coding read the list, output show is

[image]

this is wrong output, it should be show exactly same as input.

below is coding at JSP

```
StringBuffer sbURL = new StringBuffer(TRKD_WEB_SERVER);
    sbURL.append(sSearchBy);
    //sbURL.append("?request=");        
    urlFeed = new URL(sbURL.toString());
    conFeed = urlFeed.openConnection();
    conFeed.setConnectTimeout(30000);
    try{
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conFeed.getInputStream()));

        if (in!=null)
        {
            strData=new StringBuffer();
            while ((ch=in.read()) != -1)
            {
                strData.append((char)ch);
            }
        }
```

What's wrong for my coding, please kindly advice.

Thanks

Comment: So the difference is in the line breaks? Does the input use ``\r\n`` mixed with ``\n``?

Comment: ya..the different is line break...may be is  input use \r\n mixed with \n.. How should i do?